# network leave/unscribe multicast group

Tags: multicast, igmp

I have debian based server where I need to subscribe a multicast. After doing it with headless mpalyer I can see the following:

```
root@ca1:~# netstat -g
IPv6/IPv4 Group Memberships
Interface       RefCnt Group
--------------- ------ ---------------------
lo              1      all-systems.mcast.net
eth0            1      all-systems.mcast.net
eth1            1      X.X.X.X
```

where X.X.X.X is require multicast address/

In order to leave that multicast group I should send 0x17 igmp packet and this is the question, how can I do with some existing tools and not doing it C/python code?